# Crystal Reports Missing Assembly Issue

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have downloaded the sample from [Here](http://aspalliance.com/1947) i have crystal reports 2008 (12.0.0.549) and vs 2010 is installed. I am getting the following error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can any one guide how to add missing assembly

Comment: Do you get this error on your machine or on customer's?

Comment: i am getting it on my machine i am just testing it and trying to run the sample

Comment: i think i need to change Version=10.5.3700.0 to Version=12.XX something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Crystal Reports 2010](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp) and ensure that the you've NOT got a "Client Profile" selected under **Target Framework** in the **Applicaiton** tab under the projecst **Propertiese**

It didn't seem to work for me with a Client Profile.

**Note:** Cyrstal reports can still be 'designed' with CR2008.

Some more info on the SAP forum [here](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1837484&tstart=0).

Comment: There are four links available on that page which one should be downloaded (i have windows 7 32 bit)

Comment: The top one the standard EXE installer, is what i used.